# clone a wchar_t* in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to clone a path that is held in a var named szPath to a new wchar_t.

[image]

szPath is of the type wchar_t *. so i tried doing something like:

```
szPathNew = *szPath;
```

but this is referring to the same place in memory.
what should i do? i want to deep clone it.

Comment: maybe this?: wchar_t * szPathClone1 = new wchar_t(*szPath);

Comment: "but this is referring to the same place in memory." No, it isn't; it's cloning - the first character of the string.

Comment: it's a damn good thing you protected yourself from negative rating by posting a comment instead of answer.

Comment: good comment Karl, that's true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this,

```
wchar_t clone[260];
wcscpy(clone,szPath);
```

Or, if you want to allocate memory yourself,

```
wchar_t *clone = new wchar_t[wcslen(szPath)+1];
wcscpy(clone,szPath);
//use it
delete []clone;
```

Check out : [strcpy, wcscpy, _mbscpy at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

However, if your implementation doesn't *necessarily* require raw pointers/array, then you should prefer this,

```
#include<string>

//MOST SAFE!
std:wstring clone(szPath);
```

Comment: ...or _wcsdup if you want it to allocate memory for you:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Please emphasis the C++ way of doing things as this is a C++ question. Re-enforcing C behaviors just keeps us all in the dark ages a lot longer.

Comment: why don't you use std::copy?  am i missing something?

Answer (score 5):

Do not use raw C strings in C++. If you want wide character strings, you can use std::wstring:

```
#include <string>

...

std::wstring szPathClone1 = szPath;  // Works as expected
```

If you insist on using wchar_t buffers directly, you can use the wcscpy function.

PS: You also seem to be confused by pointer usage, you should first learn more about pointers.

Comment: You should also explain how to pass szPath off as a `char const*` and how to deal with constructing and using `char*` buffers in C++.  The user's obviously working with the win32 C api.

Answer (score 4):

The [`_wcsdup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) function duplicates (clones) a string. Note that this allocates new memory, so you will need to free it later:

```
wchar_t * szPathClone = _wcsdup(szPath);
// ...
free(szPathClone);
```